Radon Nikodym derivative for the sum of two measures
Suppose that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are two $\sigma$-finite measures and let $\rho=\mu+\nu$. Obviously $\mu$ and $\nu$ are both absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\rho$. I am trying to find a closed form expression of the density of $\mu$ w.r.t. to $\rho$ (possibly switching to a different probability space)?
I tried:

When one can find a measure $\eta$ such that $\mu=f \mathrm{d}\eta$ and $\nu=g \mathrm{d}\eta$ then it is easy to see that $h=f/(f+g)$ is the $\eta$-density of $\mu$ w.r.t. $\rho$.

But when I dont have access to such a representation in terms of dominating measure. Is there anything we can do?
I am fine with imposing certain regularity conditions such as purely discrete/continuous measures, but I dont want to assume the knowledge of a density w.r.t. a common dominating measure $\eta$.
This question Radon-Nikodym derivative of sum of two measures is related.
